# Retrieving number of pages of a PDF using PDF.JS fails with return

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I don't understand the following. Maybe I am missing some really stupid issue here... can anybody solve it? Thanks in advance.

I have this code in Javascript:

```
function funcLeNrPaginasPDF(strCaminhoPDF) {
    var objLivrariaPDF = window['pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'];
    var objDocumentoPDF = null; 

    objLivrariaPDF.workerSrc = '/pdfjs/pdf.worker.js';

    // strCaminhoPDF var contains the pdf doc: "documento.pdf"

    var oprCarregaPDF = objLivrariaPDF.getDocument(strCaminhoPDF);
    oprCarregaPDF.promise.then(function(objDocumentoPDF) { document.getElementById('nr_paginas').textContent = objDocumentoPDF.numPages; });
```

It works like a charm, thus, if I change document.getElementById... and put

```
alert (objDocumentoPDF.numPages);
```

it works as well... However if I place a "return" the function returns me an *undefined* variable content. Like this:

```
oprCarregaPDF.promise.then(function(objDocumentoPDF) { return objDocumentoPDF.numPages; });
```

Any thoughts why? I need a variable to hold the number of pages.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Ashamed of such unimportant and easily spot-table fault. The *return* must've been put outside the bracket of the inner function... ahmen.